# Show the toast before fragment start

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, toast

I'm beginner in Android and am trying to write a simple application. When into fragment click on button start other fragment, for that purpose:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            secondFragment.removeAllViews();
            transaction.replace(R.id.secondFragment, new DashBoardFragment());
            transaction.commit();
        }
    });
}
```

but after other fragment start show the Hello Toast, but I want show before fragment start.

Comment: why are you using `Handler`? also, I think that everything is happening so fast that you think that toast is showing after fragment starts

Answer (score 3):

Try this in `onClick` after `toasting` :-

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        secondFragment.removeAllViews();
        transaction.replace(R.id.secondFragment, new DashBoardFragment());
        transaction.commit();
    }
}, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
```

Your fragment transaction will take place after 1500 ms ( **hence your toast message would shoot up before transaction takes place** )

Your full on click method...

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            secondFragment.removeAllViews();
            transaction.replace(R.id.secondFragment, new DashBoardFragment());
            transaction.commit();    
        }  
    }, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);              
}
```

Comment: Even better if did you replace 1500 with Toast.LENGTH_SHORT

Comment: `Toast.LENGTH_SHORT` will also show after the fragment transaction @BasilBattikhi

Comment: How? once the toast finished it will replace the fragment :/

Comment: both run in different thread.. !! :) @BasilBattikhi both will run simultaneously

Comment: but i did mean something like that `new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){public void run ();},Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)`

Comment: oh now i understand , you are taking the time as `Toast.LENGTH_SHORT` cool :) .. @BasilBattikhi

Comment: Now it's a perfect solution +1